# Simple Casino War Probability

Tags: probability-theory, card-games

This question is from QuantGuide(Casino War):

You are playing a game with the casino. You and the dealer are each dealt a card from a fair, shuffled deck of 52 cards. If you have a strictly larger number than the dealer's, you win- else, you lose. What is the probability you win?

My Approach:
Let my probability of getting the greater value be S. It will be the same for my dealer. Now let the probability that I get the same value as the dealer be X. The equation will be:
\begin{equation}
2S+X=1
\end{equation}
For X we get select 1 set of 4 cards from 13 sets of 4 cards. From that, we will select 2 cards. For the total number of cases, it will be 52*51.
Hence $X=\frac{13*6}{51*52}=\frac{1}{34}$ and $S=\frac{33}{68}$.This answer doesn't pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X$, the first case has no restriction,  after the first card is chosen, we then have $3$ options out of $51$ cards.

Hence $X=\frac{3}{51}=\frac{1}{17}$.

---

Your mistake is your denominator should be $\binom{52}{2}$.

$X=\frac{13\cdot 6}{\binom{52}{2}}=\frac{13\cdot 12}{52\cdot 51}=\frac1{17}$

Comment: I guess I should have considered that the 2 cards selected from 4 cards can be distributed among the dealer and me in 2 ways. Hence it should be $\frac{13*6*2}{52*51}$ and hence the answer. Thanks for the correction.